# Azure service bus for maximum throughput how can I ensure if 100 messages are accumulated than only do read

Tags: c#, .net, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

How can I ensure to read message from queue only when n number of messages are collected. Do we have anything to ensure that.

I believe something must be there **ServiceBusProcessorOptions** to ensure this. I am using **MaxConcurrentCalls**  which is set to 100. But I get message when there is one message also.

Answer (score 0):

The short version is no, there is not currently a way to guarantee the minimum number of messages returned.

`MaxConcurrentCalls` governs how many active invocations of your handlers can happen at a single time.  In fact, the higher the number, the greater the chance that each handler call sees a smaller number of messages in a batch.

100 is a huge value for this setting and is likely to cause problems due to contention in the thread pool unless you have a machine with 32+ cores available.

**Additional Context**
When messages are requested, the prioritization is to return data to your application quickly so that the locks for the messages that have been received do not expire waiting for the additional messages needed to fill the batch, and so that your application doesn't sit idle.

The processor makes the request for the desired batch size to the network transport, which attempts to build a full batch within a ~20 millisecond window from prefetch and the network stream before returning whatever messages are currently available.  If no messages are available within the `maxWaitTime` that you've specified, nothing is returned.

Prefetch can help by making more messages available to the batch, but they have to be streamed in over the network.  Depending on the size of messages, it can take a bit to stream in enough to fill the prefetch cache and if you're consuming messages faster than the network can stream them, the cache will run dry.

An important consideration for prefetch is to remember that messages held in the prefetch cache are locked by the service, and those locks will expire if they are not consumed quickly enough.